# Is PVC an acceptable pipe for a vent stack through the roof

Tags: plumbing, vent, drain-waste-vent

I'm trying to figure out what type pipe I need for terminating a vent stack in the roof.  Is it acceptable to run 1 1/2" schedule 40 PVC through the roof for a new vent stack.

This will have 2 toilets, two showers, two sinks and one tub off this single vent (In case someone wants to comment on size).

I just didn't know if the PVC will hold up in the sun, or if there's a different type of Pipe I need to use to terminate the pipe outside.  If it is different, do you just use a boot to connect the two?  Anything special done to prevent fumes?

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44593/what-is-cellular-core-abs-pipe/44594 for information on the types of ABS pipe, with the inferior one being the most common at big box stores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

National (international) plumbing codes identify vent pipe size, length above the roof, flashing and caps.  But does not specify material.  PVC, ABS and galvanized have all been used.
You are right PVC is not the best in sun, for my area in desert south west I do not know why builders use it but they do.  But same issue occurs on solar water heating systems and pool pumping/filter systems.  So I like to coat them with at least paint, but like to use white elastomeric roof coating if I have some handy.

Comment: Yup, just give it some sun protection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use schedule 80 PVC as it is UV stabilised, however all forms of PVC are can be used in direct sunlight as long as they are painted with outdoor paint - water based normally. It will degrade over time like anything but with paint it is minimal.