# What's the best way to protect plastic drain waste vent pipes from UV damage on a roof?

Tags: roof, drain-waste-vent, roofing

What is the best way to protect plastic plumbing waste vents (DWV) where they extend above the roof?  PVC discolors and gets brittle in the sun, solid ABS gets chalky, foam cellular core ABS bends easily. Metal is an option, but rarely used these days.

What sort of UV stabilized primer and paint or other compound can work for plastic stack vent pipes?  What sort of preparation is required for painting?

See also:s
[Is PVC an acceptable pipe for a vent stack through the roof](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/98178/is-pvc-an-acceptable-pipe-for-a-vent-stack-through-the-roof/98190#98190)